# pgf stacked bar plot not displayed correctly - wrong intersection with x-axis

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I'm trying to generate a bar plot with the code below. As you can see does the bar plot not start at zero, as it should. It starts below zero!!! Can anybody help me?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz} %used for pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable} % to create diagrams, plots, ...
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

% Results IPPC
\begin{filecontents}{labelIPPC.dat}
X   start  Container    T-DO        T-MRF   MRF     T-Rec   label
1   0      335489       4894217     536423  944172  82159   \space  
2   0      428004       101754      1033659 3289363 64989   \space 
3   0      508863       101754      739925  1040748 89001   \space
4   0      254431       101754      739925  1040748 89001   IPPC\space 2013 
5   0      254431       101754      683838  1016135 86948   \space 
6   0      254431       101754      652601  991521  85590   \space 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Results of ecological analysis for future scenarios}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    ybar stacked,
    %set layers, 
    width=0.7\textwidth,
    every axis legend/.append style={nodes={right}},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.30)}, anchor=north, legend columns=1},
    x tick label style={rotate=90},
    xticklabels={Scenario 1,Scenario 2,Scenario 3,Scenario 4,Scenario 5,Scenario 6},
    xtick={1,...,6},
    point meta=explicit symbolic, % label und nicht zahl darstellen
    }

\begin{axis} [
scale only axis,
axis y line*=left,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=',
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/sci},
scaled ticks=false,
ylabel near ticks,
ylabel={UBP (Eco-points)},
ybar,
bar shift=-0.34cm, % half of bar width
bar width=0.6cm,
]
%\addplot + [color=red!50!white] table[x=X, y=start, meta=label] {labelIPPC.dat};

\addplot + [color=red!50!white] table[x=X, y=Container, meta=label] {labelIPPC.dat};
\addlegendentry{Container}

\addplot + [color=green!50!white]  table[x=X, y=T-DO, meta=label]                       {labelIPPC.dat};
\addlegendentry{Transport to drop-off site}

\addplot + [color=blue!50!white]  table[x=X, y=T-MRF, meta=label] {labelIPPC.dat};
\addlegendentry{Transport to MRF}

\addplot + [color=orange!50!white]  table[x=X, y=MRF, meta=label] {labelIPPC.dat};
\addlegendentry{Material recovery facility}

\addplot + [color=black!50!white, nodes near coords, every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west}]  table[x=X, y=T-Rec, meta=label] {labelIPPC.dat};
\addlegendentry{Transport to recycling facility}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:Results_Scenarios}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If included the commented \addplot, it starts at zero, but then the legend is out of order. I really hope someone can help me.

Thanks very much

Comment: Simply set `ymin=0` in your axis options. You should also specify the `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` in the preamble, and you only need to load `pgfplotstable`, which automatically loads `pgfplots` and `tikz` :-)

Comment: I'm already struggeling to implement compat=1.12
Did you mean a different version, because as it seems, this version does not exist

Comment: ymin=0 does indeed shift the y-axis down, but the bars don't end where they should, because they start below zero.

Comment: RE missing version: You may need to update your `pgfplots` then. The new version was released a few days ago. If you don't want to update, you can write `compat=1.11`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and building on the comments by **darthbith** the following worked for me (and also fixes your example):

Additionally to the `ymin=0`, which let's the bar start right at the axis, you add an additional `enlargelimits=true` to the axis options, to get the whitespace back between the axis and the start of the bars.

What still eludes me, though, is that I have one stacked bar plot where I do not need these options explicitly and another that *only* worked *with* these explicit options. The only difference between those plots is that the first has additional `addplot` commands, thus its bars consist of more segments.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be worth asking a separate question including your examples to resolve the last issue.